# pass an element of the viewmodel to a partialview

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

I have my main page creating tabs (jQuery UI tabs) dynamically and loading a partial view on it using Ajax. This partial view has a `viewmodel`, and contains other partial views. Partial views are `strTypd` to an element on the `viewmodel`. When I try to pass the element, I get an error.

The "main partial view"

```
@model HMSDB.ViewModels.vm_administrar_permisos

<div id="PerAdmGroupBoxUser">

  <h3>Seleccion de usuarios</h3>
  <div>
      <div id="PerAdmUsrGrid">          
          @Html.Partial("_BuscarUsuario", @Model.vmBuscarUsuario) //<-- ERROR

      </div>
      <div id="PerAdmUsrData">
          @Html.Action("_DetalleUsuario", "Usuario")
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The model of the main partial view:

```
  public class vm_administrar_permisos
    {
        public vm_usuario_seleccionado vmUsuarioSeleccionado { get; set; }
        public vm_buscar_usuario vmBuscarUsuario { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Permisos_Rol_User> roles { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Permisos_Grupo_User> grupos { get; set; }
    }
```

The child partial view:

```
@model HMSDB.ViewModels.vm_buscar_usuario


  <h3>Seleccion de usuarios</h3>
```

InvalidOperationException:

```
The passed model´s element to the dictionary is 
of type:'HMSDB.ViewModels.vm_administrar_permisos', but this dictionary requires a
model´s element of type 'HMSDB.ViewModels.vm_buscar_usuario'
```

EDIT:
Parent partial view call:

```
   function getTabContent(idT, urlC) {                               //ajax call to partial view
      $.ajax({
         url: urlC,
        type: 'GET',
       async: false,
          success: function (result) {
              $("#"+idT).html(result);
    }
  });
```

};

controller:

```
public ActionResult _Administrar()
{
    vm_administrar_permisos model = new vm_administrar_permisos();

    model.grupos = db_cm.Permisos_Grupo_User.Include("Permisos_Grupo")
                   .Where(gu => gu.id_user == HttpContext.User.Identity.Name && gu.conceder == true);

    model.roles = db_cm.Permisos_Rol_User.Include("Permisos_Rol")
                  .Where(ur => ur.id_user == HttpContext.User.Identity.Name && ur.conceder == true);  
    return PartialView(model);
}
```

Comment: show how you call the parent view from controller

Comment: done, idT is the id for the tab and urLC ="Permiso/_Administrar" or i just go to localhost:port/hmsw/Permiso/_Administrar

Comment: my suspicion is that you have outdated version of markup somewhere (_Administrar.cshtml for instance). Try specifying full path to your views starting  with "~" as the first parameter of `Controller.PartialView` and `Html.Partial`

Comment: Also, did you leave out the code where `model.vmBuscarUsuario` is created/assigned?

Comment: when u said outdated u got me thinking, i updated my EF model and delete and redo my linq querys, and looks like i also delete the vmBuscarUsuario part lol i need some sleep, tks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suspicion is that you have outdated version of markup somewhere (_Administrar.cshtml for instance). Try specifying full path to your views starting with "~" as the first parameter of `Controller.PartialView` and `Html.Partial`.

Also, did you leave out the code where `model.vmBuscarUsuario` is created/assigned?